# Call function with argument from array

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

This is simple scraper, for example where all links are stored in `var productUrls`. Then there is for loop where searching string from `var searchUrls[x][0]` and if string is included in `var productUrls`, then run specific function from `var searchUrls[x][1]`. Problem is when I call from for loop `console.log(await storeFunc);` what is in this case `searchUrls[0][1]` function with argument alzask(productUrl) is runed from var searchUrls[0][0] and that productUrl is **undefined** and shold be `productUrls[i][0]`. I'm missing something ? Or it's too complicated and can be better writed ? Thank you.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeData() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  var productUrls = [
    ['https://www.alza.sk/nest-hub-2nd-gen-charcoal-eu-d6845008.htm'],
    ['https://edigital.sk/prenosny-reproduktor/google-ga01331gr-nest-hub-2-smart-reproduktor-svetlo-sedy-p899177'],
    ['https://www.mironet.cz/google-nest-hub-2-charcoal-7-displej-wifi-bt-50-google-assistant+dp497233/'],
    ['https://www.planeo.sk/katalog/1316639-google-nest-hub-2nd-gen-chalk-hlasovy-asistent.html']
  ]

  var searchUrls = [
    ["alza.sk",alzask(productUrl)],
    ["edigital.sk","edigitalsk(productUrl)"],
    ["mironet.cz","mironetcz(productUrl)"]
  ]

  for ( i = 0; i < productUrls.length; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < searchUrls.length; j++ ) {
      var productUrl = productUrls[i][0];
      var searchUrl = searchUrls[j][0];
      var storeFunc = searchUrls[j][1];
      if (productUrl.includes(searchUrl)) {
        console.log(await storeFunc);
        break;
      }
      else if (j == searchUrls.length - 1 && !productUrl.includes(searchUrl)) {
        console.log("Product with url: " + productUrl + " doesn't have storeFunc in database.");
      }
    }
  }

  async function alzask(productUrl) {    
    var priceSelector = ".price-box__price";
    await page.goto(productUrl);
    const priceData = await page.$eval(priceSelector, price => price.textContent.trim());
    return priceData;
  }

  await browser.close();
}

scrapeData();
```

Run `async function alzask(productUrl)` where argument **productUrl** is not **undefined**, but is string url from `var productUrls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following issue with the code mentioned above.

```
var searchUrls = [
// productUrl is not defined
  ["alza.sk",alzask(productUrl)],
  ["edigital.sk","edigitalsk(productUrl)"],
  ["mironet.cz","mironetcz(productUrl)"]
]
```

The productUrl is not defined when you used it in the above code.

Following is the correct implementation. Save the function in the searchUrls and then call the function for the corresponding productUrl -

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeData() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    var productUrls = [
      ['https://www.alza.sk/nest-hub-2nd-gen-charcoal-eu-d6845008.htm'],
      ['https://edigital.sk/prenosny-reproduktor/google-ga01331gr-nest-hub-2-smart-reproduktor-svetlo-sedy-p899177'],
      ['https://www.mironet.cz/google-nest-hub-2-charcoal-7-displej-wifi-bt-50-google-assistant+dp497233/'],
      ['https://www.planeo.sk/katalog/1316639-google-nest-hub-2nd-gen-chalk-hlasovy-asistent.html']
    ]

    var searchUrls = [
    // just save the function here like this
      ["alza.sk", alzask],
    // ["alza.sk", alzask(productUrl)],
    // similar implementation for below
      ["edigital.sk", "edigitalsk"],
      ["mironet.cz", "mironetcz"]
    ]

    for ( i = 0; i < productUrls.length; i++ ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < searchUrls.length; j++ ) {
            var productUrl = productUrls[i][0];
            var searchUrl = searchUrls[j][0];
            var storeFunc = searchUrls[j][1];
            if (productUrl.includes(searchUrl)) {
                // now call the function here with the productUrl
                console.log(await storeFunc(productUrl));
                break;
            }
            else if (j == searchUrls.length - 1 && !productUrl.includes(searchUrl)) {
                console.log("Product with url: " + productUrl + " doesn't have storeFunc in database.");
            }
       }
    }

    async function alzask(productUrl) {    
        var priceSelector = ".price-box__price";
        await page.goto(productUrl);
        const priceData = await page.$eval(priceSelector, price => price.textContent.trim());
        return priceData;
    }

    await browser.close();
}

scrapeData();
```

Now the issue with your code is that it has multiple for loops which are not needed. You can make searchUrls an object and it will make your code faster like this-

```
var searchUrls = {
    'www.alza.sk': alzask,
    'edigital.sk': edigitalsk,
    // and so on...
}

for ( i = 0; i < productUrls.length; i++ ) {
    var productUrl = productUrls[i][0];
    // productUrl will split as ['https:', '', 'www.alza.sk', 'nest-hub-2nd-gen-charcoal-eu-d6845008.htm']
    // split array's 2nd index will give the corresponding searchUrl
    var searchUrl = productUrl.split('/')[2]
    var storeFunc = searchUrls[searchUrl]
    if (storeFunc) {
        console.log(await storeFunc(productUrl))
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't know that I could save the function without parentheses and and later call this function with arguments. Thanks.

Comment: Functions in javascript are javascript objects and can be saved in variables.